# On almost sure convergence of conditional martingales

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

Let $X$ be a stochastic process with natural filtration $\mathcal F_t$, and $\mathcal G_t$ another filtration. Suppose that $X$ is a *conditional martingale* relative to $\mathcal G_t$, in the sense that for all $t > s \geq 0$, we have

$$\mathbb E[\mathbb E[X_t| \mathcal F_s] | \mathcal G_s]] = \mathbb E[X_s | \mathcal G_s]$$

almost surely.

Suppose in addition $X_t$ is $L^1$ bounded, that is, $\sup_{t \geq 0} \|X_t\|_{L^1} < \infty$.

**Question:** Is it true that $\mathbb E[X_t|\mathcal G_\infty]$ converges almost surely as $t \to \infty$?